# div tag not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have created a simple application which connects to a rest api, as follows:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" >
   </script>
   <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1 id="header">A headline</h1>
       <div id = "info"></div>
       <p1 id = "p1">p1</p1>
    <form id="name" name="name">
        Please enter a switch: <input type="text" name="switch" id = "switch">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </form>

   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#name').submit(function() {
                alert('submitted');
                var switchName = $('#switch').val();
                $.getJSON('http://localhost:8081/withindex/switch','name='+switchName, processSwitches(data));
            });
        });


       function processSwitches(data) {
        alert('processSwitches');
        var infoHTML = '<p>Switch Name: ' + data.switchName +'</p>' ;
        alert(infoHTML);
        $('#info').html(infoHTML);
        $('#header').html('<h1>Switches</h1>');
       }
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

It runs, and will return an alert with the `infoHTML` string correctly, but I can't figure out why it won't update the div tag with id `info`.

Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the spaces between id and the name?
Like -> id="info"

Comment: they are whitespaces between the id attribute and equals sign and the attribute value?

Comment: you aren't preventing browser default submit of form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're invoking the `processSwitches` function inside the `$.getJSON` function. You should pass only the name of that function - without the `(data)` part:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8081/withindex/switch','name='+switchName, processSwitches);
```

Simply, this:

```
processSwitches
```

instead of this:

```
processSwitches(data)
```

**EDIT:**

You also forgot to prevent the form from submiting. Simply add `return false` at the end of the `submit` event handler:

```
$('#name').submit(function() {
    alert('submitted');
    var switchName = $('#switch').val();
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8081/withindex/switch','name='+switchName, processSwitches);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok I did that, but it still isn't updating the div tag.

Comment: @AkshaiShah your webpage is probably refreshed after you click `OK` on the alert. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're submitting the form. Upon form submition data is lost.

Try adding

```
return false
```

after

```
$.getJSON(... )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle it works http://jsfiddle.net/K3ZKA/ check your console for errors!

`strings are undefined but doesen't matter`